# Something missing in a Java program but what?

Tags: java, swing, fuse

when I execute a Java application, in Eclipse console, I obtain these errors. I am finding some difficulties to interpret...seems to me that something is missing but I can't understand what: a class, a configuration file or what?

```
[04 ott 2013 23:59:33,945] DEBUG [AWT-EventQueue-0] (OSUtils.java:getSettingsDir:109) - Sistema operativo: linux
[04 ott 2013 23:59:33,949] DEBUG [AWT-EventQueue-0] (TasksSettings.java:<init>:36) - File di configurazione: /home/andrea/.XCloud/settingTasks.xml
[04 ott 2013 23:59:33,950] DEBUG [AWT-EventQueue-0] (QuickLocale.java:loadLocale:20) - Load localization file: /com/techub/crystalice/resources/Strings_it_IT.properties
[04 ott 2013 23:59:34,205]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (GUI.java:startup:124) - XCloud|Avvio XCloud 10.7.0.3
[04 ott 2013 23:59:34,223] DEBUG [AWT-EventQueue-0] (GUI.java:startup:127) - Versione: 10.7.0.3
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[04 ott 2013 23:59:34,735]  WARN [AWT-EventQueue-0] (GUI.java:startup:248) - XCloud|Non è possibile verificare la presenza di nuove versioni di XCloud sul server cloud. Verificare la connessione verso Internet.
[04 ott 2013 23:59:34,736] DEBUG [AWT-EventQueue-0] (QuickLocale.java:loadLocale:20) - Load localization file: /com/techub/crystalice/resources/Strings_it_IT.properties
[04 ott 2013 23:59:34,798]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (GUI.java:startup:339) - Start RMI Server
[04 ott 2013 23:59:34,812] DEBUG [AWT-EventQueue-0] (OSUtils.java:getSettingsDir:109) - Sistema operativo: linux
[04 ott 2013 23:59:34,931] DEBUG [AWT-EventQueue-0] (RmiServer.java:<init>:72) - this address=127.0.0.1,port=10061
[04 ott 2013 23:59:34,935] DEBUG [pool-3-thread-1] (SyncManager.java:run:221) - nessun disco montato presente
[04 ott 2013 23:59:34,942] DEBUG [AWT-EventQueue-0] (AtmosFuseWrapper.java:checkExecutable:32) - Atmosfs trovato correttamente (/home/andrea/Documenti/XCloud/Implementazione/CrossPlatform/CrystalIceGUI/Project/data/atmosfs)
[04 ott 2013 23:59:34,945] DEBUG [AWT-EventQueue-0] (AtmosFuseWrapper.java:unmount:88) - Smonto il drive con:
    fusermount -u /home/andrea/connect_drives/a
[04 ott 2013 23:59:35,086]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (AtmosFuseWrapper.java:mount:53) - XCloud|Drive 'a' connesso
[04 ott 2013 23:59:35,087] DEBUG [AWT-EventQueue-0] (AtmosFuseWrapper.java:mount:54) - Monto il drive con:
    /home/andrea/Documenti/XCloud/Implementazione/CrossPlatform/CrystalIceGUI/Project/data/atmosfs -s /home/andrea/connect_drives/a 2f37e03f34bf4a3ba3a29fda1508b298/A06001017873135a91b4 iG8Z6WiF98yptaG6Xa2gj4BYsPs= S false false a
[04 ott 2013 23:59:35,092] ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] (GUI.java:error:477) - XCloud|Impossibile montare il drive 'a' (token-id 'A06001017873135a91b4') in '/home/andrea/connect_drives/a' 
com.techub.crystalice.fuse.FuseException: Impossibile montare il drive 'a' (token-id 'A06001017873135a91b4') in '/home/andrea/connect_drives/a' 
    at com.techub.crystalice.fuse.AtmosFuseWrapper.mount(AtmosFuseWrapper.java:67)
    at com.techub.crystalice.gui.DriversManager.mount(DriversManager.java:83)
    at com.techub.crystalice.gui.DriversManager.mount(DriversManager.java:63)
    at com.techub.crystalice.gui.GUI.startup(GUI.java:343)
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:187)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:672)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:642)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/andrea/Documenti/XCloud/Implementazione/CrossPlatform/CrystalIceGUI/Project/data/atmosfs": java.io.IOException: error=2, File o directory non esistente
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:470)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:466)
    at com.techub.crystalice.fuse.AtmosFuseWrapper.mount(AtmosFuseWrapper.java:59)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, File o directory non esistente
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:148)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
    ... 21 more
```

Someone have some idea about what is wrong?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: You need to post the code that's calling `mount`. Can you mount `/home/andrea/connect_drives/a` from the command line?

Comment: yes: andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~/connect_drives/a$ ls
prova  prova.txt  prova.txt~

Answer (score 1):

Says right here:

```
Cannot run program "/home/andrea/Documenti/XCloud/Implementazione/CrossPlatform/CrystalIceGUI/Project/data/atmosfs": 
java.io.IOException: error=2, File o directory non esistente
```

Check that `atmosfs` is there, or change configuration to point where it is.

Comment: mmm I have check: the file exist and seems to be in the mentioned directory....

Comment: @AndreaNobili: does it have correct permissions?